# How can I Fix Default Unit Tests Failing on a Working Project

Tags: angular, angular6, karma-jasmine

I have a form that works perfectly. The issue comes up when I run "ng test" on my project. I'm using the original test cases that are provided when you build a project with the cli.

Karma output:

```
AppComponent should create the app
Failed: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("
    <div id="theForm">
      <h2>Bus Form</h2>
      <form [ERROR ->]#f="ngForm" name="theForm" (ngSubmit)="addLog(f)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@3:12
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("
                name="boarded"
                [(ngModel)]="log.boarded"
                [ERROR ->]#logBoarded="ngModel"
                pattern="^[0-9]+$"
                required>
```

Component.html:

```
<title>BusLog</title>
<div id="theForm">
  <h2>Bus Form</h2>
  <form #f="ngForm" name="theForm" (ngSubmit)="addLog(f)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Boarded</label>

      <input type="number"
            class="form-control"
            name="boarded"
            [(ngModel)]="log.boarded"
            #logBoarded="ngModel"
            pattern="^[0-9]+$"
            required>
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="logBoarded.errors?.required && logBoarded.touched">
        The # of boarded is required
      </span>
      <span class="help-block danger" *ngIf="logBoarded.errors?.pattern && logBoarded.touched">
        The # of boaurded can only contain numbers
      </span>
    </div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Log } from './log';
import { LogService } from './log.service'; 
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
```

module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'BusLog'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('BusLog');
  });
```

Edit: Sorry about leaving this guy out. I could barely keep my eyes open when I created this.

Comment: Could you pleaae also add your spec.ts for this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module used for testing is not the module used for usual execution.

Thus, your `module.ts` is not used (event if it looks perfectly ok in what you have shown here).

Instead, the module is defined in your spec file.

Your spec file will typically have:

```js
describe('...', () => {
  // ...
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ... ],
      imports: [MAKE SURE FormsModule IS SHOWN HERE]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

You have to make sure the correct modules are imported in your test.

In your example, I guess `FormModule` is not imported in your test module. So the specific directive you use on your `form` are not declared, and the execution rightfully fails.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include the test file but I was half asleep at that point. I actually do have FormsModule in there already and still no luck.

Comment: And I know that setting the title in the html file will not work. I've tried using the Title service to set the title in the component but I get the same error.(that test also fails with the same response. I just figured one test was enough to show the strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add the `FormsModule` as a provider into your test file setup.

Comment: I've added the file. Sorry about that. Seems like the only piece of code I actually needed haha

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working.

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
let component: AppComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let de: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges;
  });

  it('should create the component.', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


});
```